# How to retrieve UserName and Password in unattended Azure Function

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have a runbook that is currently executed via a webhook call in order to execute some powershell code on a site.  This is been working great.

I have been instructed to convert this code to an Azure function.  No big deal, right?  Well....
I was able to get it set up without too much trouble - I created it in VS Studio and then deployed to Azure.
The problem is that in the code I need to log in and my username and password are hard-coded in the script.  When I had run this in the runbook I called
a Credential stored in the Automation account but that does not seem to be an option here.

I have seen other people ask the same question and the answer is often "application settings", which of course is not protected.
This is to run unattended so I (obviously) can't ask for credentials.  I am running PowerShell 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Key vault references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?toc=/azure/azure-functions/toc.json) with Azure Function App to access secrets. You can protect your secrets stored in Key vault [using RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli). Azure function app also provides [integration with AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) where you can use [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts#identity-based-connections) instead of secrets. Additionally you can go through [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts) regarding more information on securing Azure Functions.